# Import modules from custom package in Python

Tags: python, module

I have created my custom package in Python.

This is the structure:

```
mypackage
    ├── mymath.py
    └── __init__.py
```

In the `__init__.py` I don't have anything. In the `mymath.py` I have the following code:

```
import math

def lala(x):
    return math.sqrt(x)
```

In the Jupyter notebook I run the following (I have the script located one level above the mypackage folder):

```
import mypackage.mymath as mm   # this runs fine
mm.lala(100)
```

I get the following error:

```
name 'math' is not defined
```

The `math` module does not seem to load for my custom module.

### Update

I have a folder for example `project_x` and within that I have the file structure stated above. The *.ipynb file is located in the `project_x` folder.

The structure:

```
project_x
├── coding_here.ipynb # here is where I `import mypackage.mymath as mm` and `mm.lala(100)`
└── mypackage
    ├── mymath.py
    └── __init__.py
```

Comment: I tried the same thing and it worked without any issue. Note that my module and Jupyter notebook was in same level.

Comment: Yes this works for me also. But when i am one level above the `mypackage` forlder it doesn't, though i can load the mymath module. Hope this makes sence

Comment: But then where is your `mypackage` located ? Is it in another package or another folder ? How come the notebook is one level above then ? could yo u please share the exact directory structure , inludin Jypter notebook ?